# Web font doesn't show some letters

Tags: fonts, font-face, webfonts

I have a huge problem with webfonts, specifically - *Pluto Sanslight*, *Pluto Sansbold* and *Pluto Sans Regular*. When I install .ttf file in computer, I can write in Lithuanian letters (ą, č, ę, ė, į, š, ų, ū, ž) and everything seems perfect, but when I import fonts on my website with *@font-face*, all Lithuanian letters are converted to usual font, *not Pluto*.

There is my code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'pluto_sanslight';
    src: url('../fonts/plutosanslight-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/plutosanslight-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/plutosanslight-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/plutosanslight-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/plutosanslight-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/plutosanslight-webfont.svg#pluto_sanslight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'pluto_sansbold';
    src: url('../fonts/plutosansbold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/plutosansbold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'pluto_sans_regularregular';
    src: url('../fonts/plutosansregular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/plutosansregular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/plutosansregular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/plutosansregular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/plutosansregular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/plutosansregular-webfont.svg#pluto_sans_regularregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your web server does not provide the font files correctly.
Have you checked your browser console to look for 404 errors?

For example, is the path `url('../fonts/plutosanslight-webfont.eot');` providing correctly the requested resource?

The reason why the characters are displayed with the usual font is probably because you specified the font family including a fallback font.
Please, post your CSS code so as we can see how you specified the font-family.

Hope it helps,
Simone

Comment: Path `url('../fonts/plutosanslight-webfont.eot');` is correct and console doesn't show any 404 errors. By the way, there is new webfont as a result, only lithuanian letters (ą, č, ę, etc.) are not shown and changed to usual font.

Example from using font:

`<p style="font-family: 'pluto_sanslight';">
We create strategies, etc.
</p>`

Font is here, but not lithuanian letters, as I mention.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Problem was, that when I was generating webfont with "Fontsquirrel" ( https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator ), I had not been checked *Custom Subsetting...* and then *Lithuanian*. That's it.